# LIMIT OFFSET PERFORMANCE ISSUE IN MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance, sqlperformance

Hellow.i have a movies table with 2 million rows.i have a problem with the performance of pagination with LIMIT OFFSET in MySQL.
I want to create a movie information dataset with pagination on movies. each page should have 20 items per page.

> MY GOAL: I WANT FAST PAGINATION on my query
> result ( query have 8 filters or more on indexed column ) and the pagination should be specific ( let say I am on the
> page 2 and I want to go to page 800000 without a large time delay.

***create a query for movies table  is like below:***

```
CREATE TABLE `movies` (
 `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `adult` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `backdrop_path` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `is_collection` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `collection_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `budget` double NOT NULL,
 `geners` json NOT NULL,
 `imdb_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `themoviedb_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `original_language` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `original_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `overview` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
 `popularity` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
 `poster_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `production_companies` json NOT NULL,
 `production_countries` json NOT NULL,
 `release_date` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `revenue` double NOT NULL,
 `runtime` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `spoken_languages` json NOT NULL,
 `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `tagline` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `video` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `vote_average` double NOT NULL,
 `vote_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `imdb_rate` double(8,2) NOT NULL,
 `meta_rate` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `rotten_rate` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `movies_themoviedb_id_index` (`themoviedb_id`),
 KEY `movies_imdb_rate_meta_rate_rotten_rate_index` (`imdb_rate`,`meta_rate`,`rotten_rate`),
 KEY `movies_runtime_title_budget_index` (`runtime`,`title`,`budget`),
 KEY `movies_popularity_revenue_original_title_index` (`popularity`,`revenue`,`original_title`),
 KEY `movies_imdb_id_index` (`imdb_id`),
 KEY `title` (`title`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1345714 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

> ok now I use 2 options that I see on the web and I want to use some filter on the movies table and each column that I want a filter on it has an index for performance.
>
> NOTE THAT ALL DATA IN MOVIES TABLE ARE THE SAME BECAUSE I WANT ON EACH
> FILTER GET ALL TABLES TO TEST PAGINATION ALL MANY DATA RESULT.OF
> COURSE IT IS POSSIBLE IN REAL WORLD APP THERE IS MORE THAN 1 MILLION
> WITH FILTER.

**OPTIONS THAT I USE:**

1. pagination with LIMIT OFFSET
2. pagination with Key Seeker

**option 1:**

```
 #THIS QUERY RUN LES THAN 1 secends
 SELECT * FROM movies * FROM movies WHERE
 rotten_rate=78 AND imdb_rate=8.40 AND meta_rate=98 AND
 budget=87 AND title="some text" AND revenue=85785 AND
 popularity=700 AND title='is the same in all rows';
```

when i do limit offset on resault i use query like below:

```
#THIS QUERY RUN FOR SOMETHING BETWEEN 12 and 24 secends
 SELECT * FROM movies * FROM movies WHERE
 rotten_rate=78 AND imdb_rate=8.40 AND meta_rate=98 AND
 budget=87 AND title="some text" AND revenue=85785 AND
 popularity=700 AND title='is the same in all rows' LIMIT 20 OFFSET 800000;
```

***I search on the web and find a better SOLUTION like below***

**SOLUTION 1:** that i found from : [here](https://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/)

```
#THIS QUERY EXECUTE FOR LESS THAN 1 seconds.
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id from movies  m LIMIT 20 OFFSET 800000)AS t1 INNER JOIN movies on t1.id=movies.id;
```

but when I use solution 1 with the filter it becomes slow(i don't know why)

```
  #THIS QUERY EXECUTE AFTER 8 OR 15 seconds.
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT id FROM movies WHERE
     rotten_rate=78 AND imdb_rate=8.40 AND meta_rate=98 AND
     budget=87 AND title="some text" AND revenue=85785 AND
     popularity=700 AND title='is the same in all rows' LIMIT 20 OFFSET 800000)AS t1
     INNER JOIN movies on t1.id=movies.id
```

OPTION 2:

(KEY SEEKER METHOD FOR PAGINATION)

> I found from [here](https://taylorbrazelton.com/posts/2019/03/offset-vs-seek-pagination/) I should mention this is nod good in my case
> because this method works efficiently only for infinite scrolling or
> next and before pagination. you simply can not skip to a specific
> page. let say you on page 1 and you want to go to page 800000. then
> this method is not good at all because you need the last primary on
> page 799999 but you are on the page let say 4.
>
> I search a lot for a solution that performs pagination with a specific
> page jumping from any page to any other page. but I just found these
> two approaches.any body can help me? I want anybody who contributes to
> the MySQL community or development team to help this because I know
> this is not just my problem. **thank you all my friends**

Comment: WHEN YOU TYPE SOMETHING LIKE THIS it gives the impression that you're yelling, and no one wants to help someone that is yelling at them. Please edit your question to calm it down a little bit... Additionally, if you're looking for optimization, consider posting your question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com or https://dba.stackexchange.com. Stackoverflow is for specific coding problems and solutions.

Comment: Pagination without `ORDER BY` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: thank you @The impaler but mysql order by default with id primary key

Comment: @DaniyalMadmolil Never heard of anything like it. Can you point to the documentation about it?

Comment: This question is not well formulated. Voting to close.

Comment: Don't use `OFFSET`; instead, "remember where you left off" -- http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination

Comment: dear @Rick James thank you so so much.your weblog was all I need.you are the best .

Answer (score 0):

Many queries "run quickly" as soon as the query engine knows how to deliver the first page-ful of results to you (and, how many rows there are to return).

In your case, you are probably forcing the SQL engine to actually page through hundreds of thousands of result rows in order to obtain the slice you want.  That not only takes a long time, but puts a great burden on the SQL server itself – keeping it from being quickly able to respond to other requests.

I think that you need to fundamentally re-consider your approach so that your SQL result sets are never *nearly* so large.  You need to find a way to "paginate" in the SQL `WHERE` clause itself.